# Unexpected bytes used in chrome storage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm writing an extension that makes use of the [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API. I want to truncate each item to make sure it is below the maximum bytes threshold of the storage (local and sync).

The documentation states that the byte size of each individual item is

> measured by the JSON stringification of its value plus its key length.

I use the following code to calculate the expected byte size:

```
new TextEncoder().encode(JSON.stringify(value)).length + key.length
```

I use the following code to check actual usage:

```
chrome.storage.<storage-area>.set({ [key]: value }, () => {
   chrome.storage.<storage-area>.getBytesInUse(key, bytes => {
        console.log("actual bytes in use", bytes);
   });
});
```

Given a key of "test" and a value of "abc", the expected byte usage is 9b. The actual byte usage is 9b.

Given a key of "test" and a value of "«ταБЬℓσ»", the expected byte usage is 23b. The actual byte usage is 23b.

Given a key of "test" and a value of "<", the expected byte usage is 7b. The actual byte usage is 12b.

The storage is of course cleared between each check.

In the last example, what is causing those 5 extra, unexpected, bytes? What am I missing?

Edit: I'm using Google Chrome version 73.0.3683.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It can be a bug but even if it's not, you're trying to match the undocumented internal specifics of the implementation which aren't guaranteed to remain constant between the versions of the browser. You can inspect the source code of Chromium at https://cs.chromium.org.

Comment: Yes you're right, either way I'll have to handle any errors occurring when saving, but it made me very curious. I suppose this is what I'm looking for: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/extensions/browser/api/storage/settings_storage_quota_enforcer.cc?type=cs&g=0&l=27. I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason thanks to w0xx0m's comment.

Chrome/Chromium replaces the less than character with "\u003C" to prevent script execution.

Source code can be found [here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/base/json/string_escape.cc?gsn=Write&g=0&l=64).